# Adding layers to the control bar

Tags: javascript, css, mediaelement.js

i'm using media element player on my page. I have a div that i want to show\hide according to the control bar state - visible or not. I see the script (mediaelementplayer.js) has some way for doing that but i can't get it right:

```
// any additional controls people might add and want to hide
t.container.find('.mejs-control')
.css('visibility','visible')
.css('display','block');
```

I've tried adding class="mejs-control" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you verified that the code that adds those css styles is being executed?

Comment: it is being executed. i think my problem is that my overlay div is not in the same class, or something like that, can't figure it out.